# Material Design Form Error

Tags: html, css, forms, material-design

I'm working on material design of HTML form. I don't want `required` input text filed. But my material design works only if input has `required attribute`. I've tried to change css from `:valid` to `:not(:focus)`, `:invalid`, `:optional` but it did not work.

**Problem:**
If I enter in the input field, The label goes to top, after typing something when I leave the input field the label comes to its initial position. I don't want the label to come to its original position after typing. Label should go to top only after typing.

**Here is my form:**

```css
.form-row {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 20px;
  color: #999;
  cursor: text;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.form-textbox,
.form-submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-textbox:focus~.form-label,
.form-label:after {
  top: 10px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <input type="text" id="form-email" class="form-textbox">
  <label for="form-email" class="form-label">Testing</label>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Required field only help to check it is valid or not valid through that you are gonna validate the text box otherwise you have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some custom javascript for the expected functionality.
@Khushbu Vaghela, I've updated little bit of css and javascript as per your need

```js
function hideLabel(){
  txtEmail =  document.getElementById('form-email')
  lblEmail =  document.getElementsByClassName('form-label')[0]
  if(txtEmail.value != ''){
    lblEmail.classList.add("form-label-content");
  } else {
    lblEmail.classList.remove("form-label-content");
    lblEmail.innerText = 'Testing';
  }
}
```

```css
.form-row {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .form-label {
      position: absolute;
      top: 17px;
      left: 20px;
      color: #999;
      cursor: text;
      transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    .form-textbox,
    .form-submit {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
    }

 
    .form-textbox:focus ~ .form-label {
      top: 10px;
      left:12px;
      font-size: 10px;
      color: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .form-textbox:not(:focus) ~ .form-label-content {
      top: 10px;
      left:12px;
      font-size: 10px;
      color: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
      <input type="text" id="form-email" onFocusOut="hideLabel()" class="form-textbox">
      <label for="form-email" class="form-label">Testing</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I don't want to hide a label, I want it to be at the top after leaving the input.

Comment: Can you please help me to get the label on top after typing and leaving the field. @Siddaram H

Answer (score 1):

Like Siddaram H say, you can do it with a simple js function. But if you want it to always be visible, transform `.form-textbox:focus` in a class like `.edited`

```js
if (txtEmail.value != '') {
  lblEmail = document.getElementsByClassName('form-label')[0]
  lblEmail.classList.add('edited');
}
```

```css
.edited {
  top: 10px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and will send the feedback. Thank you :)

Comment: Check your code, maybe there is a conflict with another class or change lblEmail = document.getElementsByClassName('form-label')[0]; by lblEmail = document.querySelector('.form-label');

Answer (score 1):

<del>You can check if the input field contains text by using the `:valid`-pseudoclass.</del>

**EDIT: Sorry I just read your question more careful**

```css
.form-row {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 20px;
  color: #999;
  cursor: text;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.form-textbox,
.form-submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-textbox:focus~.form-label,
.form-textbox:valid~.form-label,
.form-label:after {
  top: 10px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <input type="text" id="form-email" class="form-textbox" required>
  <label for="form-email" class="form-label">Testing</label>
</div>
```

---

Another way to do this with pure CSS is using the `:placeholder-shown`-pseudoclass. Unfortunately, this does not work in IE or Edge at all.

```css
.form-row {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  left: 20px;
  color: #999;
  cursor: text;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.form-textbox,
.form-submit {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-textbox:focus~.form-label,
.form-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown)~.form-label,
.form-label:after {
  top: 10px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <input type="text" id="form-email" class="form-textbox" placeholder=" ">
  <label for="form-email" class="form-label">Testing</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but I want it to work in IE.